# Mail Accounts form fails to submit data

Tags: webform-civicrm, ajax

I have CiviCRM (4.6.3) plus CiviHR installed on a Wordpress 4.2.2 (multisite installation). I go to Administer=>CiviMail=>Mail Accounts. Then I try to create a new account or edit the default one. I enter my data into the form and click Save.

Result:
The form just keeps on loading forever. In the browser debugger console, the following line appears after submitting the form:

POST http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/mailSettings&action=update&id=1&snippet=json 404 (Not Found)

I've tried all the troubleshooting tips from here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0, but with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why this 404 is happening or how I can further debug it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue - CiviCRM 4.6.5 Joomla 3.4.1
PHP 5.3.29
MySQL 5.5.42